# sql select biggest updated primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

Is there any way to get biggest primary key value of the table after update statement?

I have a C# function takes parameters like, table name, and values to update a table. It generates a dynamic sql statement and executes it. So when I run function, if there is an insert it returns me last inserted id as int, there is not problem but if there is an update then I cannot get biggest updated id of the table.

for example I have a table like; RowId, Name, Lastname

```
-- this statement may update multiple rows
Update Person
set name = 'sample name'
where name = 'name' and lastname = 'lastname'
-- get last updated rowid here
```

Comment: Last? In what order? Without an order, question makes no sense.

Comment: do you have a updated_time column?

Comment: @SamD Yes I do, But I am tring to find a query which will work for all update statements, not individual select.

Comment: @MitchWheat biggest primary key updated.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I PK 1,000,000 was updated last week and PK 3 was updated today, you want PK 1,000,000?

Comment: "Last updated" <> "biggest"

Comment: There is a solution for this in this thread.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439110/sql-server-update-a-table-by-using-order-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure why you're after this, can you explain further. However, i'd use the `OUTPUT` syntax. For example:

```
DECLARE @UpdatedIDs TABLE
(
    ID INT
)

-- this statement may update multiple rows
Update Person
set name = 'sample name'
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @UpdatedIDs
where name = 'name' and lastname = 'lastname'
-- get last updated rowid here 

SELECT MAX(ID) AS LastUpdatedID
FROM @UpdatedIDs
```

You will end up with a variable table called @UpdatedIDs which you then select the `MAX()` ID from the rows you've just updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to output all the rows that were updated into a table (variable).

Then you could manipulate that however you want.

But I fail to see the usefulness of knowing the 'last' or even the largest primary key updated. Perhaps you could explain why you need this?

Also, your question implies that you are using a Natural key for the table's Primary key. I would use a surrogate key instead. Use an integer IDENTITY column as the primary key.

Comment: I have a C# function takes parameters like, table name, and values to update a table. It generates a dynamic sql statement and executes it. So when I run function, if there is an insert it returns me last inserted id as int there is not problem but if there is an update then I cannot get last updated id of the table.

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
UPDATE Person
SET name = 'sample name', @lastUpdatedId = id
WHERE name = 'name' and lastname = 'lastname'
```

Comment: I'm not even sure if this syntax is documented, but I'm not sure how you can guarantee that it will give the "biggest" value of `id` that was updated, in the case where multiple rows are affected. [Here is one case where it breaks](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8dcd/1).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - There's an obscure corner of the Internet where the syntax is documented: [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx). Read that again: _"where the syntax is documented"_. Semantics are generally up for grabs. You may now post a link to your blog that undocuments the syntax.