# How to Add Order to an existing table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table called Products. Let say this is my table,

```
ID    Name     ParentID
--    ---       --------
1      a        NULL
2      b        NULL
3      a1       1
4      a2       1
5      b2       2
6      b2       2
```

Now I need to add [Order] Column with respect to ParentID,

```
ID    Name     ParentID    Order
--    ---       --------   ----
1      a        NULL        NULL
2      b        NULL        NULL
3      a1       1            1
4      a2       1            2   
5      b2       2            1  
6      b2       2            2
```

Creating [Order] is trivial but inserting record is a bit tricky part

Comment: @RoyDictus, I am new-bie?

Comment: Well you are here long enough to know the rules. So show us your work please.

Comment: Do we really need to blame somebody who hasn't ever used `ROW_NUMBER`? What would somebody try if he didn't know about this function?

Comment: @Smileek Cursors come to mind. I believe that every question, regardless of the asker's ability or difficulty of the question, needs to show an attempt at solving the problem oneself, even if it's just sharing a few thoughts about what won't work.

Comment: @Dukeling, yeah, probably you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE  [Products]
SET  [Products].[Order] = PTT.[Order]
FROM
    [Products]
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PT.ParentID ORDER BY ID) AS [Order]
                FROM [Products] PT
                WHERE PT.ParentID IS NOT NULL) AS PTT ON PTT.ID = [Products].ID
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you. Just update your anser to, UPDATE [Products]
   SET  [Products].[Order] = PTT.[Order]
FROM [Products]
  INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PT.ParentID ORDER BY Name) AS [Order] FROM [Products] PT  WHERE PT.ParentID IS NOT NULL) AS PTT ON PTT.ID = [Products].ID

Comment: [You don't need a self join here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439110/sql-server-update-a-table-by-using-order-by/3439180#3439180)

Comment: @user960567 - It's SQL Hint's answer. I'll leave it up to them if they want to remove the unnecessary join.