# sql - how to add a rank column to an existing table

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have the following table:

```
my_table = sa.sql.table('my_table',
    sa.Column('id', sa.BigInteger),
    sa.Column('employee_id', sa.BigInteger)
)
```

and I want to add a 'rank' column using alembic.
The addition itself is pretty straight forward using `add_column` but I also need to populate that column using sqlalchemy based on existing information (each employee_id has its own rank ordered by the id).

For example, the following table:

```
id    employee_id    rank
--    -----------    ----
1          1          1
2          1          2
5          1          3
3          2          1
4          3          1
6          3          2
```

The problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677287/how-to-add-order-to-an-existing-table).

The only difference is that I need it working for sqlalchemy on top of both mysql and oracle (a more generic solution is needed).

How can I populate the rank column using engine.update?

**EDIT 1**:
This question is not about how to insert or update records through alembic. It's about finding a query that will do a specific thing and running this query using engine.update

Comment: This is not a question about how to insert/update records through alembic. I've updated my question to reflect that. Please read the entire question before dismissing it.

Comment: Then please rewrite the question to focus on the specific problem. Right now it's rather vague.

Comment: Thanks, I just understood that "Any Thoughts?" is not that focused :)