# SQL Server Set-Based Update With Multiple Matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, set-based

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465384/update-row-from-query-with-multiple-matches), which presents the same situation. Trying to do a set-based update, and the table to be updated matchesmultiple rows in the table being used for update values. A minimal example is below:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempUpdates (ID INT, TheValue VARCHAR(100))

CREATE TABLE #Target (ID INT, TheValue VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Target (ID, TheValue)
VALUES (1, 'START')

INSERT INTO #tempUpdates (ID, TheValue)
VALUES (1, 'tUpdate'),
(1, 'SecondUpdate')

UPDATE t
SET t.TheValue = u.TheValue
FROM #Target t
INNER JOIN #tempUpdates u ON u.ID = t.ID

SELECT * FROM #Target
```

The other question's answers went over ways to get a specific update value. What I'm wondering is in the above example, or other similar situations, how does SQL Server decide which value is the new value? First row returned? Something else?

Comment: An arbitrary matching value is chosen.  This is highly discouraged in `update` queries.

Comment: Totally understand it's bad practice. Found some legacy code doing this and got curious. But arbitrary? Like SQL Server flips a coin? I was imagining maybe the first row returned, or last row returned, or max rid or something.