# Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY -- When updating Table Abonnement

Tags: mysql, sql-update

When trying to update to include a price in the previous made table Abonnement I get the error code mentioned in the title. I looked around on the net but it seems my syntax is correct?

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

DELETE FROM Abonnement;
DELETE FROM AbonnementType;

INSERT INTO AbonnementType(beginDatum,eindDatum,type)
VALUES("2013/1/1","2013/1/1","DAGPAS");

INSERT INTO Abonnement(betaald,AbonnementType_ATypeId,FietsType_FType,Klant_klantId,Code,Wachtwoord)
VALUES(false,(SELECT MAX(ATypeId) FROM AbonnementType),1,1,"test","test");

UPDATE Abonnement as a
JOIN FietsType AS af ON a.FietsType_FType = af.FType
JOIN AbonnementType AS at ON a.AbonnementType_ATypeId = at.ATypeId
SET a.prijs = af.Prijs * (at.eindDatum + at.beginDatum)
ORDER BY AbonnementId DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `WITH` object?

`With updateSyn As
(
...
)

Update updateSyn set ...`
[SQL Server: UPDATE a table by using ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439110/sql-server-update-a-table-by-using-order-by)

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround and now it does what is has to do.

```
UPDATE Abonnement as a
JOIN FietsType AS af ON a.FietsType_FType = af.FType
JOIN AbonnementType AS at ON a.AbonnementType_ATypeId = at.ATypeId
JOIN (SELECT MAX(AbonnementId) as max_id FROM Abonnement) as aa ON a.AbonnementId = aa.max_id
SET a.prijs = af.Prijs * (at.eindDatum + at.beginDatum)
```