# How to SQL UPDATE in a certain order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I want to learn how to process table rows when updating column(s), in a certain order (and not in the random or in the order that the records were created).

To illustrate my question, in the made-up example below I want to set the Ranking according to the date_time such that the older records are processed first (and get lower ranking).

```
create table #testTable (customer_id char(20), ranking int, date_time
Datetime, pk_value int identity )
go

insert into #testTable (customer_id, date_time) values 
('MICROSOFT', '20110202')
insert into #testTable (customer_id, date_time) values 
('MICROSOFT', '20120202')
insert into #testTable (customer_id, date_time) values
('MICROSOFT', '20090512')
go
declare @Rank int
set @Rank = 0
update #testTable set @Rank = @Rank + 1, ranking = @Rank
```

Comment: You should label your question with the database you are using.  From the syntax, I surmise that it is SQL Server.

Comment: You can always do `UPDATE table SET column="value" WHERE foo = bar ORDER BY any_column;`

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Yes, you are right, I meant SQL Server. I will do it next time.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo  Thank you for your suggestion.  When I try your syntax I get error "Incorrect syntax near ORDER"

Comment: @Hidalgo Is it possible to post  your code, where it gave "Incorrect syntax" error?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo  Add the following to my UPDATE .. example above:
where customer_id = 'MICROSOFT' order by date_time
and I get the error.

Comment: @Hidalgo. Okay, I'm sorry. Now that it's clear you're talking about SQL Server in particular, it seems that the solution is not quite as simple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439110/sql-server-update-a-table-by-using-order-by. My suggestion above certainly pertains to MySQL. You may have no choice than to spend some effort along the line suggested by GordonLinoff.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo  Thank you for the reference to another post.  I am beginning to see the light.

Comment: One of the fundamentals of database normalization is to not store calculated values.  That being the case, why do you want to do so?

Comment: @DanBracuk  The above example was just an example.  The actual case involves the table where the programs stores in-stock quantities of a certain item, different row storing a quantity at a different price received at different time.  When taking a certain quantity of the item from stock, I need to reduce the in-stock quantity (hence UPDATE the in-stock table) in the order of older records first (FIFO).   Therefore, my UPDATE needs to process records in the order of the In-Date.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can set the ranking using the (appropriately named) ranking functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by date_time) as seqnum
      from #testtable t
     )
update toupdate
    set ranking = seqnum;
```

Comment: Gordon, I will have to study to understand your code (new syntax to me). Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Gordon, what is the purpose or why do you have the "t.*" in your expression?

Comment: Your answer using row_number() over is helpful (I learned something new). And it answers the question of the example I used to illustrate it. But my actual UPDATE is more complicated where I need to update not a "ranking" column but some quantity column.  And it has to be done in a certain order.  So using "seqnum" does not work for me.  I should have created a different example to illustrate my question.   Thank you.

Comment: You should give this the check for answering the stated question

Comment: Hidalgo . . . If you have a different question, you should ask it as a new question (with sample data and desired results).  You should not ask new questions in a comment.