# SQL Order By and Update a Column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-order-by, common-table-expression

I have the same issue listed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439110/sql-server-update-a-table-by-using-order-by), but I have tried the solution and I am getting a SQL error 1288- I'm thinking I am poorly translating SQL server to SQL or this method has been deprecated. Is there a current way of doing this?

I need to Order By a column to then iterate through my new column, adding a new order and better upkeep for future inserts and deletes. My current SQL query for updating the new column looks like this ( same as the given solution above ):

```
With cte As
    (
    SELECT ColumnToOrderBy,NewColumn,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnToOrderBy) AS i
    FROM TableToUpdate
    )
UPDATE cte SET NewColumn=i
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Right, I'm using Heidi running on MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went around a cte and just created an explicit temp table with the two necessary columns, ran the ROW_NUMBER function and then set the original table's column to the new sorted temp column. Code Below:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp 
    (ColumnToOrderBy INT,
    NewColumn INT);
INSERT INTO temp
    SELECT PrimaryKey,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnToOrderBy) AS NewColumn
    FROM TableToUpdate;
UPDATE TableToUpdate update
INNER JOIN temp t ON update.ColumnToOrderBy= t.ColumnToOrderBy
SET update.NewColumn= t.NewColumn;

DROP TABLE temp;
```

If working with large tables I don't imagine this is a quick or efficient solution, but for a small fix this works.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because MySql does not support (yet) updatable ctes.

Assuming that `ColumnToOrderBy` is unique or the primary key, so that the order is defined uniquely, you can do it with a self join in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE TableToUpdate t
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnToOrderBy) rn FROM TableToUpdate) r
ON r.ColumnToOrderBy = t.ColumnToOrderBy
SET t.NewColumn = r.rn;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8ORijj5w).

Comment: ColumnToOrderBy is not unique or this would be a great solution, appreciate the help!

Comment: @CoolHands if `ColumnToOrderBy` is not unique then `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnToOrderBy)` may return arbitrary values. So, how does your query work? The order of the rows must be uniquely defined.

Comment: Previously this table was sorted automatically by legacy gen files and it only focused loosely on that OrderBy statement. Now I want to have user sorting CRUD ops, hence the need for a new ordered column. Since the current ordering is not unique I am able to just do a mostly correct in place update