# How to update the Top (20) records with using Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to update the Top (20) records with using Select query?

Table1 (table records are in for loop) has 60 records. At a time, I want to get first 20 records based on table column="TEXT", then update those 20 records with column="TEXT1".

After that, I will pick the next 20 records (21-40) and again update as above.

I'm using below query, but it will update the first 20 records after next 20 (21-40) records it will not work.

Comment: Why 20 at a time?  Are you dealing with millions of records here?  Generally databases work best on set based operations.  and updating 60 records to say "TEXT1" in a single update statement would be far more efficient.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  some support fetch some others we'd have to generate a row number and useit..

Comment: "I'm using the below query".. you forgot to add the query.

Comment: You can use a CTE to run the subquery / get the top 20 results, then run the update against that... but that can be prone to locking...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584315/sql-update-top-with-order-by

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
Update tableName set Column = 'TEXT1' where column = 'TEXT'  ;
```

or if need be conditionally update...

```
UPDATE tablename set column = case when column = 'TEXT' then 'Text1'
                                   else column = 'OtherText' then 'Text1Other'
                                   else column = 'StillOtherText' then 'Text1Other2' end
WHERE column in ('TEXT','OtherText','StillOtherText');
```

Comment: this is the good solution: rather than the loop, the single query cover every expect with case

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a while-loop that checks for the existence of 'TEXT'.  If the check returns true, then the top 20 primary keys are selected as part of an update statement.

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM Table1 
               WHERE yourcolumn = 'TEXT')
BEGIN
UPDATE Table1
   SET yourcolumn = 'TEXT1'
 WHERE primarykey IN (
                       SELECT TOP 20 primarykey
                         FROM Table1
                        WHERE yourcolumn = 'TEXT'
                     )
END
```

Comment: i think this could be enhanced by checking for the row count of the updated query rather than doing a while exists which does a full table scan