# Update Top 1 record in table sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Query

```
UPDATE TOP (1) TX_Master_PCBA  
SET TIMESTAMP2 = '2013-12-12 15:40:31.593'
WHERE SERIAL_NO IN ('0500030309') 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP2 DESC
```

with `serial_No` Column in `TX_Master_PCBA` table i have 10 records but i want to update the latest `TIMESTAMP2` to current datetime.

the above query is throwing error :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'.

Comment: though the question states SQL-SERVER, for whom search for MySql solution there is an easier faster way `UPDATE TX_Master_PCBA SET TIMESTAMP2=NOW() WHERE SERIAL_NO='050030309' ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @TomerW - life saver, thank you. didn't even think to do a limit! saved me hours, ty

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
UPDATE TX_Master_PCBA
SET TIMESTAMP2 = '2013-12-12 15:40:31.593',
G_FIELD='0000'
WHERE TIMESTAMP2 IN 
(
   SELECT TOP 1 TIMESTAMP2
   FROM TX_Master_PCBA WHERE SERIAL_NO='0500030309'
   ORDER BY TIMESTAMP2 DESC   -- You need to decide what column you want to sort on
)
```

Answer (score 66):

```
WITH UpdateList_view AS (
  SELECT TOP 1  * from TX_Master_PCBA 
  WHERE SERIAL_NO IN ('0500030309') 
  ORDER BY TIMESTAMP2 DESC 
)

update UpdateList_view 
set TIMESTAMP2 = '2013-12-12 15:40:31.593'
```

Comment: WORK FINE ! THANK YOU

Answer (score 31):

Accepted answer of Kapil is flawed, it will update more than one record if there are 2 or more than one records available with same timestamps, not a true top 1 query.

```
    ;With cte as (
                    SELECT TOP(1) email_fk FROM abc WHERE id= 177 ORDER BY created DESC   
            )
    UPDATE cte SET email_fk = 10
```

Ref Remus Rusanu Ans:-  [SQL update top1 row query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860975/sql-update-top1-row-query#)

Comment: What If I want to use Join here and set values from that table ?

Answer (score 13):

For those who are finding for a thread safe solution, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799974/890890).

Code:

```
UPDATE Account 
SET    sg_status = 'A'
OUTPUT INSERTED.AccountId --You only need this if you want to return some column of the updated item
WHERE  AccountId = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 AccountId 
    FROM Account WITH (UPDLOCK) --this is what makes the query thread safe!
    ORDER  BY CreationDate 
)
```

Comment: +1 for thread safe, although when `AccountId` is not unique you're going to have to work in a cte as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/32395239/4496560 to grab only one single record.

Comment: I found that this SP updated ALL records so I made the top line look like this UPDATE Account Top (1)

Answer (score 12):

When `TOP` is used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `MERGE`, or `DELETE`, the referenced rows are not arranged in any order and the ORDER BY clause can not be directly specified in these statements. If you need to use TOP to insert, delete, or modify rows in a meaningful chronological order, you must use `TOP` together with an `ORDER BY` clause that is specified in a subselect statement.

`TOP` cannot be used in an `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements on partitioned views.

`TOP` cannot be combined with `OFFSET` and `FETCH` in the same query expression (in the same query scope). For more information, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Answer (score 9):

It also works well ...

```
Update t
Set t.TIMESTAMP2 = '2013-12-12 15:40:31.593'
From
(
    Select Top 1 TIMESTAMP2
    From TX_Master_PCBA
    Where SERIAL_NO IN ('0500030309')
    Order By TIMESTAMP2 DESC
) t
```