# SQL ORDER BY on Update- update last record with condition

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to update the last record of table Log (the field with the latest TimeAccessed) given that TimeExited is null, and the computername is the same as the "cm" parameter. I have this but get error, "missing semicolon at end of sql statement"

what is wrong??

```
dbs.Execute "UPDATE Log " _
& "SET TimeExited = " & Format(CloseTime, "\#hh:mm:ss AMPM\#") _
& " WHERE TimeExited is NULL AND ComputerName = '" & cm & "'" _
& " ORDER BY TimeAccessed DESC" _
& " LIMIT 1; "
```

nothing wrong with first 2 lines, work perfectly fine, it's the last two that give problems

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539095/update-top-1-record-in-table-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL doesn't use `LIMIT n` it uses `TOP n`, and as mentioned in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539095/update-top-1-record-in-table-sql-server) cited in the comments to your question, you aren't allowed to use TOP in the way you've described. Instead, you'll need to do something along these lines:

```sql
UPDATE Log 
SET TimeExited = CloseTime
WHERE TimeExited IS NULL 
    AND ComputerName='r2d2'
    AND TimeAccessed IN
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 TimeAccessed
            FROM Log
            WHERE TimeExited IS NULL 
                AND ComputerName='r2d2'
            ORDER BY TimeAccessed DESC
        )
```

Comment: you are right, I did not search enough. This solved it, thanks