# update on the first row after order by

Tags: sql-server, database

```
select top 1 feedback from c_history where email='hassan.shahid94@yahoo.com'
and id = 1 order by ti desc

update c_history set feedback =2 where email='hassan.shahid94@yahoo.com' and
id =1 order by ti desc
```

by this query i am getting the data of perfect position, but i don't wanna fetch the data from that position. i want to update the data on that position. the problem is i can't use order by in update query. 
Select query is perfectly working and update query isn't working. 
please help me out from this problem

Comment: Why is the order important?

Comment: @juergend it's my requirement i  have used inner query but it ain't work too.

Comment: But it does not change anything if you update in a different order.

Comment: @juergen i have to update the first row which i am getting through order by and top 1 in select query

Comment: set rowcount 1; update [...]; set rowcount 0;

Comment: @IngoB it's updating my 5 records.and i should update that record which i am fetching through select query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539095/update-top-1-record-in-table-sql-server