# Update column as Duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have a table with three columns, A, B, and status.

[image]

first, I filter the table to get only duplicate value

using this query

```
    SELECT  A
   FROM Table_1
     GROUP BY  A
    HAVING COUNT(A) >1
```

the output :

[image]

In the second step, I need to check if column B has a duplicate value or not, if have duplicate I need to update the status as D.

[image]

I try this query

```
UPDATE Table_1

 SET status = 'D'

 WHERE exists

 (SELECT  B
  FROM Table_1
 GROUP BY  B
HAVING COUNT(B) >1)
```

but it is updated all the rows.

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539095/update-top-1-record-in-table-sql-server

Comment: See [Correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you need using *row_number* to identify any group with a duplicate and an updateable CTE to check for any row that's part of a group with a duplicate:

```
with d as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by a,b order by a,b) dn
    from t
)
update d set d.status='D'
where exists (select * from d d2 where d2.a=d.a and d2.b=d.b and d2.dn>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an updatable CTE *without any further joins* by using a windowed `COUNT`

```sql
WITH d AS (
    SELECT *,
      cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b)
    FROM t
)
UPDATE d
SET status = 'D'
WHERE cnt > 1;
```