# How to update only one of duplicated rows in SQL without primary keys?

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that have the following columns:

| st_id | sbj_id | desc | scr | sbm_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 10 | Q2 | 7.4 | 2021-05-03 17:03:32 |
| 2001 | 10 | Q1 | 8.0 | 2021-04-03 18:07:35 |
| 2011 | 10 | Q1 | 5.0 | 2021-04-03 19:07:35 |
| 2001 | 10 | Q2 | 7.4 | 2021-05-03 17:03:32 |

I want to update the `st_id` value on the last row of the table to `2011`. How can I update only one of the duplicated values in this table, when there is no primary key in it?

Result expected:

| st_id | sbj_id | desc | scr | sbm_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 10 | Q2 | 7.4 | 2021-05-03 17:03:32 |
| 2001 | 10 | Q1 | 8.0 | 2021-04-03 18:07:35 |
| 2011 | 10 | Q1 | 5.0 | 2021-04-03 19:07:35 |
| 2011 | 10 | Q2 | 7.4 | 2021-05-03 17:03:32 |

Comment: This is what primary keys are for.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that there is no primary key in this table. I will update the question.

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS, you could do something like [update the top 1 record from a select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539095/update-top-1-record-in-table-sql-server).

Comment: I am using MariaDB, connected with MySQL Workbench.

Comment: then I'd expect `LIMIT` to work as it does in SELECTs.

Comment: The fact you are dealing with this is due to poor database design. If your rows ought to be unique, but aren't, your database should have ensured that rows are truly unique. Whether that's by adding an IDENTITY column that adds a unique value to every row, or by the use of a unique index that would prevent non-unique rows from making their way into the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema and insert statement:

```
 create table testTable(st_id int, sbj_id int, description varchar(50), scr float, sbm_dt datetime);
 insert into testTable values(2001, 10, 'Q2',   7.4,    '2021-05-03 17:03:32');
 insert into testTable values(2001, 10, 'Q1',   8.0,    '2021-04-03 18:07:35');
 insert into testTable values(2011, 10, 'Q1',   5.0,    '2021-04-03 19:07:35');
 insert into testTable values(2001, 10, 'Q2',   7.4,    '2021-05-03 17:03:32');
```

Update query:

```
 update testTable set st_id=2011 where st_id=2001  order by sbm_dt desc limit 1
```

Query:

```
 select  * from testTable
```

Output:

| st_id | sbj_id | description | scr | sbm_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 10 | Q2 | 7.4 | 2021-05-03 17:03:32 |
| 2001 | 10 | Q1 | 8 | 2021-04-03 18:07:35 |
| 2011 | 10 | Q1 | 5 | 2021-04-03 19:07:35 |
| 2001 | 10 | Q2 | 7.4 | 2021-05-03 17:03:32 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=906db1d4a5f56be30177f35c7b4b8b37)*

Comment: @AndréFerreira you are most welcome. But, if possible, you might consider changing your database design. Best wishes.