# Best Practice to Update EAV table rows

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update, rows, entity-attribute-value

I have the following table:

```
SubjectID AttributeID ValueID
1         1           2
1         1           3
1         2           1
2         1           3
2         2           1
1         3           1
```

An attribute can have multiple values (multiple appearances in the above table for the same attribute).
There is no constraint of how many appearances for the same attribute (different value).

I wan't to Update the Subject with SubjectID=1, to change the ValueID to only 1 where the AttributeID is 1, so

**Before:**

```
Select * from Subject WHERE SubjectID=1 AND AttributeID=1
--returns:
SubjectID AttributeID ValueID
1         1           2
1         1           3
```

**After:**

```
Select * from Subject WHERE SubjectID=1 AND AttributeID=1
--returns:
SubjectID AttributeID ValueID
1         1           1
```

I am doing this with a stored procedure with optional parameters (all null and update only the attributes that were provided), now this is not an issue. My question is:

What is the best practice to update this rows? I see the following answers as viable:

1. Delete all the rows that contain the specified attribute, then insert the new ones;
2. If there is only one attribute of that type (for the specified subject) update that one (not a good solution if there are more than 1 for the same attribute)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using the multiple values for each subject-attribute pair elsewhere?  If not, I'd recommend removing these and updating the table design to prevent re-occurance.  This would simplify *all* the queries/SPs you write on this table.  If you need to keep these records then yes, I would delete then insert - within a transaction.

Comment: I don't really have a choice, I had to implement this design, almost done, only stuck on updates o.O

Answer (score 2):

You could update just one row and then delete the others like so:

```
set rowcount 1;

update Subject
   set ValuedID = 1
 where SubjectID = 1
   and AttributeID = 1;

set rowcount 0;

delete Subject
 where SubjectID = 1
   and AttributeID = 1
   and ValuedID <> 1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work.  The update isn't limited to a row.  From the example Subject-Attribute-Value 1, 1, 3 and 1, 1, 2 would both be updated to 1, 1, 1.  The delete would not find any records.  This would leave the OP with 2 records, instead of the requested 1.

Comment: You can [limit updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860975/sql-update-top1-row-query), via a CTE, to a set row count.

Comment: My current implementation is, delete one by one and insert one by one, I am wondering if changing to this implementation will give better performance, I think it reduces the task with one query, instead of deleting n rows you delete n-1

Comment: Sorry IngoB! I completely missed the row count statements. Must be time for more coffee. Nice solution.

Comment: Using [**`set rowcount`** is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql), use `top (n)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`set rowcount`** is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql), use `top (n)` instead.

> Important
>   Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in a future release of SQL Server. Avoid using SET ROWCOUNT with DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. For a similar behavior, use the TOP syntax. For more information, see TOP (Transact-SQL).

---

```
update top (1) Subject
  set ValueID = 1
where SubjectID = 1
  and AttributeID = 1;

delete Subject
where SubjectID = 1
  and AttributeID = 1
  and ValueID <> 1;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ATDKI87027

returns:

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+
| SubjectID | AttributeID | ValueID |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
|         1 |           1 |       1 |
|         1 |           2 |       1 |
|         2 |           1 |       3 |
|         2 |           2 |       1 |
|         1 |           3 |       1 |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
```