# vb.net access query for updating

Tags: vb.net

is d query rite ?
q = "update FIRSTBBA WHERE FBBANAME<>"" ORDER BY FBBANAME"
Need to update a table in ascending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is not complete. You can use inner SQL statement based on your requirement and update the table based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning a value to FIRSTBBA. 
Also, not sure what database you're using but I don't think SQL server allows an order by clause in an update statement. you would have to refer to a post like this one: [How to update and order by using ms-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655010/how-to-update-and-order-by-using-ms-sql)