# Update in an Order By series

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to run an `UPDATE` statement over multiple records in an `ORDER BY` series. This is because my update includes a scalar function, which uses the early updated value. Can anyone suggest a better way **other than looping through** in the desired order?

---

Sorry I should have done it very earlier, The Scenario is..

My problem was I have a table variable and it has hierarchical records,

### ID  SlNo    result

1   1.0 True

2   1.1 True

3   1.1.1   True

4   1.1.2   False

5   1.2 True

6   1.2.1   False

7   1.2.2   False

8   1.2.3   False

9   1.2.4   False

And the tree structure is,

1.0

```
1.0 > 1.1

1.0 > 1.1 > 1.1.1
```

1.0 > 1.1 > 1.1.2

1.0 > 1.2

1.0 > 1.2 > 2.2.1

1.0 > 1.2 > 2.2.2

1.0 > 1.2 > 2.2.3

1.0 > 1.2 > 2.2.4

I want to update the results to a table and if all the child branches are "False" then its parent should go as "False". For that I need to update rows in the "descending Order" and also must see all its child branches are "False". Can i do it in a single update statement? How can I say Order by in My Update Query?

Comment: Can you show some table structure?

Comment: Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655010/how-to-update-and-order-by-using-ms-sql

Comment: You could calculate your new values in a SELECT statement, then use the result set to update the real table.

Comment: What exactly should be updated based on what? And please do *not* just respond in a comment, but update your question instead (there's an `edit` link under the post's body).

Comment: i'm very sorry, i was late to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a query that produces the values that you want using a select.  This query will probably make use of the row_number() function to ensure ordering.

Then, use this query for the update.

As a simple example, if you want to update a column to be a sequence number for a table, where the order is specified by col1, then you would do:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by NULL order by col1) as seqnum
from table t
```

Now put this into the update:

```
with newvals (select t.*,
                     row_number() over (partition by NULL order by col1) as seqnum
              from table t
             )
update table
    set column = seqnum
from t
where t.id = table.id
```