# Update with Priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here is the request:

```
UPDATE  TOP (1) InnerPortal.Feedback.QueueFeedback
SET Busy = 1, BusyBy = @uid
Output inserted.*
WHERE (
        AccountCode = @account and
        (Done is null or Done = 0) and 
        (Busy is NULL or Busy = 0) and 
        ((DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HOUR, Utc, @utcNow)) >= 9 ) and
        (DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HOUR, Utc, @utcNow)) <= 20))
)
```

It gets first founded "non busy" record where the key field is `AccountCode`.
If record not found request returns nothing.
Next I have an ordered list of `AccountCode` and the target is  to release a special logic:
I need to create something like a loop in this request.
It will get first `AccountCode` from list and try to update.

- if success - it will stop and will return  `Output inserted.*`
- If update was not successful request will get second entry from my accounts list and try to update again.

If the loop is over and nothing was updated - `Output inserted.*` returns nothing (like now).
Is it possible to release in single request? Thanks!

Comment: What database and version were you using? Please tag the relevant database version as the answers may vary depending on the database server (and its version) you were using.

Comment: `•if success - it will stop and will return Output inserted.* ` And loop should stop here or continue?

Comment: Why are you using a loop for an update? Also, you are using top 1 but there is no order by so you have no way of knowing what row will be effected.

Comment: The target is to 'hook' (set Busy = 1) to ANY row where `AccountCode = @account`. Where is many rows with same `AccountCode` and request need to 'hook' anyone of them - top(1) helps.

Comment: @SeanLange `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is non-deterministic by design.  Although `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` support `TOP`, *none* of them support `ORDER BY`.  See [Limitations and Restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655010/how-to-update-and-order-by-using-ms-sql) is the common workaround if you need it deterministic.  I've only ever used it when I need to limit I/O and each iteration naturally removes records from the set, like moving 10 million records 10,000 at a time.

Comment: I understand how it works. thanks though for finding an explanation of the way to deal with it.

Comment: @user2598575 I think the problem you are facing is because you are using a loop to do dml. Perhaps you could modify your whole process so it doesn't have to do this RBAR style of manipulating data.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE  TOP (1) InnerPortal.Feedback.QueueFeedback

```
SET Busy = 1, BusyBy = @uid
Output inserted.* 
from InnerPortal.Feedback.QueueFeedback
join account 
  on AccountCode = account.id
 and AccountCode = @account 
 and (Done is null or Done = 0) 
 and (Busy is NULL or Busy = 0) 
 and (     (DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HOUR, Utc, @utcNow)) >= 9 ) 
       and (DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HOUR, Utc, @utcNow)) <= 20) )
```